# Comparison with string read from file returns false even when they look the same

Tags: java, string, equals, string-comparison

I'm trying to read a string from a `.csv` file (separeted by `;`) and  then compare the first column to the `login` string. Here is my code:

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("MyCSV.csv");
BufferedReader entry = new BufferedReader(file);
String row;
row = entry.readLine();
do {
    String[] value = row.split(";");
    if (login.equals(value[0])) {   // login is passed as an argument to his function
         // do something
    }
    row = entry.readLine();
} while (row != null);
```

I can read the entire file, but I'm not being able to search for the first user register. The `login` comparison always returns `false` to the first one. I tried:

```
if (value[0].equals(login)) 
if (value[0] == login)
```

An example in console:

```
// I've put this inside `do while`
System.out.println(value[0] + " and " + login + " = " + login.equals(value[0]));
```

And the result is:

```
leonidas and leonidas = false
rafatcb and leonidas = false
davinci and leonidas = false
login and leonidas = false
```

If I compare to `"rafatcb"`:

```
leonidas and rafatcb = false
rafatcb and rafatcb = true   // true, as expected
```

I also tried the following code, but it still returns `false` for `"leonidas"`:

```
value[0].trim().equals(String.valueOf(login.trim()));
```

---

As suggested in the comments, I printed using `.toCharArray()`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(value[0].toCharArray()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(login.toCharArray()));
```

And the result was:

```
[, l, e, o, n, i, d, a, s]
[l, e, o, n, i, d, a, s]
```

Comment: When you *think* strings are equal, but `a.equals(b)` is returning false, try printing `Arrays.toString(a.toCharArray())`, similarly for `b`. There may be non-printing characters.

Comment: btw, never ever ***value[0] == login*** with strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are reading from a file there may be non printable characters in your variable `value[0]`. You can replace them as below

```
value[0].replaceAll("\0", "").equals(login)
```

and it should work fine.